# I want to display all properties of a Neo4j node in this fashion: "node.name" has an attribute "node.property" of value "value(property)" in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Would like to display the properties of a node is a meaningful expression:
"Node.name" has an attribute "attribute" of value "value" in Cypher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return, for each node `n`, a collection of such strings:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n, KEYS(n) AS ks
RETURN
  [k IN ks |
    '"Node.' + n.name + '" has an attribute "' + k + '" of value "' + n[k] + '"'
  ] AS str_collection;
```

If you just want to get the individual strings, you can unwind the collections:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n, KEYS(n) AS ks
WITH
  [k IN ks |
    '"Node.' + n.name + '" has an attribute "' + k + '" of value "' + n[k] + '"'
  ] AS str_collection
UNWIND str_collection AS str
RETURN str;
```

[UPDATE]

In addition, if you want to ignore the `owner` and `perms` properties:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n, [k IN KEYS(n) WHERE NOT k IN ['owner', 'perms']] AS ks
WITH
  [k IN ks |
    '"Node.' + n.name + '" has an attribute "' + k + '" of value "' + n[k] + '"'
  ] AS str_collection
UNWIND str_collection AS str
RETURN str;
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!

Comment: How do I exclude certain attributes from the list, for example, i don't want the attribute 'owner' and attribute 'perms' appearing in the list.  Thanks again!

Comment: Extraordinary!  I'm having difficulty finding good documentation on Cypher programming

Comment: So Cybersam, is there another way I can contact you - email or phone number perhaps?  Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not designed to share private messages, and I would rather not make my contact info public.